# Using side thrusters on a missile to create an angular acceleration

Tags: rockets, aerodynamics, thrust, torque

Assume a rocket is standing on the ground with mass = 1000 kg, and near the top of rocket we apply a force of 100 N for say 1 sec, now assume that this is sufficient to tip the rocket over/start tipping over.

If the rocket is in mid air and accelerating at 30 m/s<sup>2</sup>, then likewise how much force would be required to tilt it $\small\sf{\pi/180}$ rad or change its trajectory by some degree? Please neglect the change of mass due to consumption of fuel because the value calculated with this assumption is going to be a a value higher than required, so that is not an issue.

Will the force required in mid air be the same as the force required on the ground with no acceleration?

Answer (score 3):

On the ground, assuming a free-standing rocket, the force required stabilising the rocket is gravity.

To tip, the rocket needs to rotate about the point(s) of contact with the ground. This will involve raising the rocket's centre of mass -- the wider the base, the higher it'll need to be lifted, so the more stable the rocket will be.

In flight, stability (or not) is provided by aerodynamics, so the forces involved are completely unrelated. you will need to know the speed and direction of airflow, air pressure, and design of the rocket to calculate the aerodynamic forces. This will not be an easy calculation

In flight, net forces acting on the rocket will not directly cause a rotation of one degree or otherwise, but will cause an increase in the speed of rotation

Comment: Thankyou JCRM for replying.
For example, during spacex's first stage booster recovery, they had used cold gas thrusters to properly orient the booster for its descent. I understand dynamics might vary during an ascend and descend, also the fact that we are dealing with very different masses in both the cases. But could you shed some light on the thrust produced by those cold gas thrusters and how much angular acceleration they must have created to orient the rocket.
I am a total beginner at this topic, and am working on a major project, please forgive my lack of knowledge. Thankyou

Comment: If you just wanted to know the angular acceleration in a vacuum you would need to know the moments of inertia for the vehicle. You also need to know how far the thruster is from the COG and the thrust vector. That's just for one thruster in a vacuum. In the atmosphere, it becomes a lot more complex because you need to know all the aerodynamic forces on the vehicle. Since all this stuff isn't known to the public it's impossible to calculate.